# Jsp Loading large amount of data into memory?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, installation

how can i load data into memory with a tomcat server ?

i have a java class that load data from a file.
i want to load the data into memory once and that every time the client request a page that uses that class the data will be used from the memory.

for example

```
class MyClass
{
      HashMap data = new HashMap(100);
      public void LoadDataFromFile()
      {.....}
      public void UseTheData(String input)
      {....}
      public MyClass(){ LoadDataFromFile();}  // c'tor load data
      public SetInput(String Input)
      {
           UseTheData(input);
      }
}
```

and in my jsp file

```
Myclass myclass= new MyCass();
myclass.LoadDataFromFile();
myclass.UseTheData();
```

i know i should use JSTL in the jsp file

if i use the scope="session" will the data loading will remain ?

```
<jsp:useBean id="myclass" class="MyClass" scope="session">
<jsp:setProperty name="myclass" property="input" value="blabla" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

if i do the data loading in the constructor, can i make sure the class is init only once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it in your web.xml file. In the `ServletContextListener`, when the application is initialized, read the file and store it in an attribute of the `ServletContext`. This attribute is then easily accessible from your Java and JSP code.

Comment: my java class dont know this servlet , so i will need to pass data from the servlet to my class , right ?

Comment: replace scope="session" with scope="application", and you'll access the object stored in the ServletContext attribute. But jsp:useBean is really something from the ancient days. You should really use an MVC framework and stop using Java and jsp:xxx tags from the JSP.

Comment: i have inherited the code, moving all into a framework is not an option right now :(. if i use the scope="application" so will the jsp:useBean will only create a new bean if there isnt one already  ?